Vuforia engine initialized for scene without any AR
I am experimenting with Vuforia in Unity. I found out that my device has problems accessing the camera, so I am waiting for feedback on that.
In the mean time I want to continue developing without AR, so I removed the AR camera and the Image target. But still I see error messages related to Vuforia in the Android Logcat. How is that possible?
Created a new scene that has no AR references at all.

By default, Vuforia always initializes when an app is started and before the first scene is loaded.
If you want to disable this behaviour, you can enable Delayed Initialization in the Vuforia Configuration, which you can find in the Resources folder of your project. As mentioned above, this option is disabled by default.

Additionally, if you want to know more about the lifecycle of Vuforia, I recommend giving this page a look: https://developer.vuforia.com/library/getting-started/vuforia-engine-api-unity
